# LINQ .Contains on list

Tags: linq

I'm facing some problem with LINQ query.
I had 2 querys which will get some info from two different databases for me, then in 3rd query I'm trying to "join" first two querys and get some info from them.

Here is the code for 3rd query :

```
        var test = (from z in list1
                    where list2.Contains(z.Group)
                    select new
                    {
                        z.delivery,
                        z.Number,
                    }).ToList();
```

I'v got error on

```
        list2.Contains(z.Group)
```

Which tells me that i cannot convert from string to anonymous type.

Here is also code for list2 :

```
        var list2 = (from gTowarowe in db.Towarowes
                     where gTowarowe.typ == mon
                     select new
                     {
                         Towarowe.grupa
                     }).ToList();
```

Can someone help me with this ? 
I can't join the result of list2 because i don't have any equal columns.

Edit:

[image: This is they output when i got select new]
 :
[image: And this is the one with new list2 query]

Comment: May this will help `list2.Select(x => x.grupa).ToList().Contains(z.Group)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list2` is anonymous type.

```
list2 = new {...}
```

`list2` must be string list.

```
 var list2 = (from gTowarowe in db.Towarowes
               where gTowarowe.typ == mon
               select gTowarowe.grupa
              ).ToList();
```

Updated

```
var test = (from z in list1 
where list2.Any(i => i.grupa.Contains(z.Group)) 
select new 
{ 
z.delivery, 
z.Number, 
}).ToList();
```

Comment: It's a value from DataBase

Comment: @JustSomeNewbie My bad Not `z.Group` It is list2 Remove `new` in linq query Answer is updated

Comment: Now instead of values in list2 i got Length20 for each row, so it kinda doesnt return value which was returned earlier

Comment: It is `select gTowarowe.grupa` Not `Towarowe.grupa` Try it again

Comment: I can't post pic in comment but i will update mine question in a sec - about  output which I got before from list2 and now.

Comment: Check oryginal question, this Length 20 i got with your new query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118283/discussion-between-neer-and-justsomenewbie).